# How to use d3.format or d3.time.format to map a whole week (Monday - Sunday)?

Tags: javascript, json, date, d3.js, nvd3.js

i am quite new to d3.js. I am using NVD3 (http://nvd3.org/) (therefore i use d3v3, not v4) to generate a chart. My input data is a JSON-array looking like this:

```
data = [[0,43],[1,32],[2,4],...,[167,21]]
```

These are aggregated values. The first value is the time (168=7days*24h). 0 stands for any monday between 00:00 and 00:59, 1 would be monday 1:00-1:59, 26 would be tuesday 2:00-2:59 and 167 would be sunday 23:00-00:00. I do **not** want to represent a specific week with specific dates (like Tuesday, 16-08-30). Thats why i use the 168 hours one week contains of.
I am trying to map these values on the scale of the x-axis of my chart and i think the functions d3.format and d3.time.format are the right ones. But i really can not get it done.
The result should look like this: [Chart Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lu7HC.png).

---

**There a some problems i can not resolve:**

1. How to add seven days with 24h each day to the x-axis?
2. How to set the ticks of the axis between my bars (because my bars represent the values between the hours, so the first bar represents everything what happened between monday 00:00 and monday 00:59)?

**Note: I do NOT want to represent a specific week (e.g. 16-08-22 until 16-08-28)!**
I would be very grateful if someone could help me finding a solution! Thanks a lot! =)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new array setting a start date and adding hours according to the first value of each inner array. Click "run code snippet" to see the new array with dates.

```js
var data = [[0,43],[1,32],[2,4],[3,11],[4,42],[5,34],[6,14]];

var newData = [];

data.forEach(function(d){
  var firstDate = new Date(2016, 01, 01);
  var tempDate = new Date(firstDate.setHours(firstDate.getHours()+d[0]))
  tempArray = [tempDate,d[1]];
  newData.push(tempArray);
});

console.log(newData);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Here, `(2016, 01, 01)` is just an example, you'll have to set it according to your needs.

Even better, you could push an object to `newData`, making it an array of objects:

```js
var data = [[0,43],[1,32],[2,4],[3,11],[4,42],[5,34],[6,14]];

var newData = [];

data.forEach(function(d){
  var firstDate = new Date(2016, 01, 01);
  var tempDate = new Date(firstDate.setHours(firstDate.getHours()+d[0]))
  tempObject = {date: tempDate, value: d[1]};
  newData.push(tempObject);
});

console.log(newData);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

This way, you can use `newData` as your dataset, using `d.date` and `d.value` accordingly.

Comment: Do you have an idea how i can display not a specific day on my x-axis like in your example (2016-02-01T04:00:00.000Z), I would like to have an axis like: Monday from 0-24h, Tuesday from 0-24h, ... Sunday from 0-24h.

Comment: After your edition, you have a *different* question, which makes me want to delete my useless effort. Well, for your new question, use an ordinal scale instead. Because if you stop to think about your requirement you're gonna see it's a little bit paradoxical: you want a date that's not a date...

Comment: Sorry for that. You are right, i do not want a date object. My problem is, that i do not have an idea, how i can format the ordinal scale in a way that it shows me seven days of a week with 24 hours each. I do not even have an idea which d3 methods to use.
Can you show me a coding example of how this could work? That would be great! Thanks a lot!